# problem in https

Tags: magento2, https

I would like to spend my site in https.
The problem is that I get an error when I make the change

[image]

[image]

how can i to resolve this bug.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding a trailing / at the end of your URLs? The error suggests that you are not using a valid URL in the "Base URL" field.

Comment: yeeess, thank you very much!!this is good.it missed the trailing!!However on the front, when I am in http, I am not redirected in https

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your question. Https can be quite tricky, have you got an SSL certificate yet? You should open another question on this separate issue.

Comment: yes, i have a ssl certificate, in administration, it works, not in front

Comment: Have you set "Use Secure URLs on Storefront" to Yes?

Comment: yes i configured this parameter, i flush the cache and reindex but i have the problem too

Comment: I believe you just need to set the "Unsecure Base URL" to https too as Magento uses it everywhere.

Comment: i it's good, I have parameterized "https" on "unsecure base url" and it works.thank you.it's stronge

Comment: Glad I could be of help.